# How to prevent Internet Explorer to display a page in intranet mode when Domain matches AD-Domain

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, tomcat, active-directory, intranet

I have a site that will show up unter a domain like superengeneering.com.

Unfortunately this is the domain of the Active Directory as well and so Internet Explorer keeps displaying this page with intranet settings.

How can I keep all the company's Internet Explorers from displaying it in intranet mode?

The site is a Tomcat application on Apache Linux webserver.

Thank you for suggestions,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set compatibility mode? Must be the first line within the head-section.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But no change. User still has to manually change that.